# How can I stop the Music app from launching when headphone is plugged in?

Tags: motorola-droid, music

I have a Moto Droid, running Android 2.2 (Froyo), although this behavior also existed on 2.1.   Whenever I plug something in the headphone jack, the Music app will start up (sometimes with a bit of a delay) and start playing something (generally Christmas music).
More often than not, I'm plugging in headphones to use Google Listen to listen to podcasts... if Listen is already running, I may end up with both apps playing at the same time.

The Music app doesn't seem to have any settings that would affect this behavior.  Is there some way, short of deleting all of the music so that there's nothing *to* play?

Comment: I have _almost_ the same problem; in my case, though, music doesn't start when I plug in the headphones, but rather, when I press the little button attached to them.

Comment: I upgraded to a new phone running Gingerbread about two months ago; haven't seen the problem since then, so it could be fixed.

Comment: Alas, I'm running Gingerbread.

Comment: Five years later, now on Lollipop - the same story with Google Play Music starting automatically when a bluetooth connection is made with my vehicle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been reported as a known issue on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5134). There's a long list of 79 comments which seem to indicate that rooting and adding a program called "Autostarts" fixes the problem. This is obviously not something everyone is going to want to do... be careful if you go that route.

Comment: CyanogenMod has had this fixed since 5.0.8.

Comment: Thanks; I'd searched for the relevant bug before, and somehow not found that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Headset Blocker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.idunnolol.headsetblocker) widget to disable that behavior.

Comment: It looks promising.   I'll give it a try.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! 
Go to: Settings; General
Select: Context Awareness
Select: When earphones are plugged in
Then click the slide to disable.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you plug in your headset click the Music On The Go Event in smart connect and then go to the options and disable Smart Connect. Worked on my Sony Xperia Z3 on Droid 5.0.2