# Media Player starts playing when I unplug headphones

Tags: 2.1-eclair, media-player, motorola-milestone, headphones, bugs

The stock media player on my phone has an annoying behaviour. Whenever I unplug the headphones, if the media player is paused or not running, it immediately starts running and playing my playlist. This is very annoying because everyone in the room is forced to listen to my songs until I manage to tap (twice) the Music Widget.

Has this been happening to anyone else? And what did you do to fix it?

*Note: I'm not sure if it's Android's stock player or if it's Motorola's stock player, it's just called "Music". 
Note 2: From the comments, it seems this is Android's stock music app.*

**Motorola-Milestone, firmware 2.1-update1.**

Comment: Could you specify what phone and Android version you have?

Comment: And FYI the Music app is the stock Android music player.

Comment: @jmbouffard: My bad. Added it now.

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/379/how-can-i-stop-the-music-app-from-launching-when-headphone-is-plugged-in

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/random-music-playback-winamp-cubed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in Android (even in certain Eclair systems).

There's a widget called [Headset Blocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.idunnolol.headsetblocker) that when added to any of your homescreens and activated prevents the music player from playing whenever you unplug your headest. Freeware and it works. See if it helps.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it for now.

Comment: Headset Blocker is not available for my phone. Where from I can see alternative app ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Motorola in the question, this might be your problem: The Droid and Milestone were having this problem on Android 2.0.1 or less. It was corrected on Android 2.1. So update your phone to the latest version and it should be corrected.

Comment: I should have specified, I'm running 2.1-update1.

Comment: It's really odd because I have the exact same configuration and it corrected the music auto start behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem on my Motorola Droid 1.  I used Tasker to "stop music" on certain headset events.  [See my answer here.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/random-music-playback-winamp-cubed/4962#4962)