# Optimus V music player starts playing unexpectedly, solution?

Tags: music-player

I have an Optimus V, and I have the default music widget on the desktop. Recently it started playing unexpectedly after I paused it. It could be in the middle of the night and more frequently during the day. Because of this I have to turn it off during the night. Any advice on how to keep the music player from playing unexpectedly.

Comment: Also see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/media-player-starts-playing-when-i-unplug-headphones and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/random-music-playback-winamp-cubed.  Hopefully between these three questions, one of the answers will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, of all the posts you refer I think the last is the most relevant. It recommends installing headset block, I'll be trying that. adam

Comment: i am happy to report the problem has disappeared by itself.

Comment: @AdamSO Please either provide this as answer and mark it accepted *or* delete this question.